# Division of Al Cheit

Tags: tefilla, number, yom-kippur, viduy-confession

[Al Cheit](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32573&st=&pgnum=17) has a chorus line ועל כולם, אלוה סליחות, סלח לנו, מחל לנו, כפר לנו after the first 20 Al Cheits, then after the next 12, then after the next 12. Who made this division? Why was it not divided more evenly?

Comment: The Jeckishe (German) siddur _Sfas Emes_ has a different, and more even, division.